# How to use redisTemplate to read @Cacheable data in redis?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

I am using @Cacheable to cache data into redis.

@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "configDao")

That works perfectly.

Now I want to build APIs to use redisTemplate to read/update/delete data in redis directly.

If I use redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("configA") to get specific value, it works fine,but I want to use scan or range operation to get all data in configDao.

I tried redisTemplate.opsForZSet().range("configDao~keys", 0, -1), and also 
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().scan("configDao~keys", ScanOptions.NONE)
But failed with exception:
2017-01-21 13:27:04 ERROR 2252896 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.w.s.ErrorPageFilter    - Forwarding to error page from request [/cache] due to exception [Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'configA': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@778c300c; line: 1, column: 69]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'configA': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@778c300c; line: 1, column: 69]]
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'configA': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@778c300c; line: 1, column: 69]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'configA': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@778c300c; line: 1, column: 69]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationUtils.deserializeValues(SerializationUtils.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeValues(AbstractOperations.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations.range(DefaultZSetOperations.java:105)
  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'configA': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
   at [Source: [B@778c300c; line: 1, column: 69]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3528)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2686)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:878)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2929)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:128)
    ... 119 common frames omitted

Data in redis:
-- redis stores keys of configDao in configDao~keys.
ZRANGE "configDao~keys" 0 -1
1) "configA"
GET configA
"[\"model.Configuration\",{\"name\":\"configA\",\"value\":\"804\"}]"

Could anyone help to tell me how to use redisTemplate to read @Cacheable data in redis?

Thanks a million.

Comment: Have you tried to access the cache via the cache manager? Obtain the `RedisCacheManager` bean, get the appropriate cache and then you can operate on the data. Please keep in mind that how Spring Data Redis serializes cache data and how it maintains the cache is an implementation detail which can change without further notice.

Comment: Thanks, @mp911de, I tried use redisCacheManager to get RedisCache, but unlike Ehcache  it doesn't have methods to get all keys or iterate all elements.